# During debug scala in intellj, can we pause on a statement, and then run other code?

Tags: scala, debugging

Sometimes I need interactive with scala console during debug. What I am doing now is: write a class with a method, and let that method return some object, then in scala console, I import that class ,create a new instance and run the method to get a object, then doing interactive thing with that object. If I need to modify that method, then I have to first change in IDE, then exit console, re-run console and import the class (since the class is change), to run the method again. This takes time, if it possible in IDE, set a breakpoint, run until that breakpoint, and then kick off a console, and doing interactive thing in that console?

Answer (score 0):

The way I work within intellij is to use the terminal console, and have that in the lower third of my IDE window, and then have SBT (console) or scala just running in there.   That way you can just switch between windows and evaluate expressions you need to from there.   If you want to evaluate specific (in place) expressions such as those that are only in context within the currently debugged block of code, then I think that you might be able to do that via the Watch window.  There is an option in Intellij 14 which pops up a separate evaluation window.  (Not tried this with Scala though to be honest, but works well with Java).